# WCF Application Caching Implementation

Tags: .net, web-services

i just wondering how the .net wcf application caching is implemented ?? It's single thread or multiple thread?? and if it's multiple thread how we enforce application caching to be single thread. Thank You :)

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by single or multiple thread in your question above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF doesn't come with its own caching implementation. You are left on your own to use, say, the Cache object that comes with ASP.NET or if you want to use a third party tool or Microsoft's Caching Application Block.